# Zuul proxy that discovers routes dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, netflix-zuul

I have a simple Zuul app that has a single route in the application.yml to route to my microservice. It's working.

However, what I'm looking for is a more dynamic solution where I can wire up routes dynamically, either through code or perhaps by POSTing to some Zuul endpoints during a build (possibly by using springfox and a swagger definition from microservices).  I could not find an API for Zuul.

I'm somewhat aware of Eureka and that seems like a solution to abstract away the routing by doing discovery. However, I'm curious if there's a solution without introducing Eureka. If there's a way to wire up these routes in Zuul during a build vs. having to edit the application.yml every time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go for Eureka this will actually work ootb. Zuul as packaged in spring cloud will automatically expose every service using its name. So if you register a service called `users` in Eureka, Zuul will automatically create a route `/users` forwarding to the instances by default. That will only allow simple url structures but should solve your problem.

Please see the [official documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy) for details:

> By convention, a service with the ID "users", will receive requests from the proxy located at /users (with the prefix stripped). The proxy uses Ribbon to locate an instance to forward to via discovery, and all requests are executed in a hystrix command, …

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have found this article that goes over the basics of Eureka and registering a few clients: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-cloud-netflix-how-works-service-registratio      To have the Gateway app (Zuul) register, I guess I'm missing the piece that makes the Zuul app 'aware' of Eureka.  Is it just a matter of the an entry in the application.yml file for the Zuul app? I'll continue to research myself. Thx.

Comment: @Mike updated my answer with link to the spring cloud documentation.

Comment: Complementary reading https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/2-0/common/service-registry/connectors.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually editing a blog post about this exact topic (**Routing and Filtering using Spring Cloud Zuul Server**) but the source code has been available and working for some time now. Feel free to use it as a reference:

- https://bitbucket.org/asimio/zuulserver
- https://bitbucket.org/asimio/discoveryserver (in case routes are configured with serviceIds)
- https://bitbucket.org/asimio/demo-config-properties/src (Zuul-Server-refreshable.yml where routes are dynamically updated).

Look at the refreshable `Spring` profile settings. This `Zuul` setup works with both, hard-coding routes url or discovered using `Eureka`.

It also acting as a Spring Cloud Config client so that routes could be dynamically updated via Git, which is also covered in another blog post: [Refreshable Configuration using Spring Cloud Config Server, Spring Cloud Bus, RabbitMQ and Git](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/02/02/Refreshable-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-Spring-Cloud-Bus-RabbitMQ-and-Git.html).

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely take a look.  One thing I'm struggling with at the moment is the fact that I have oauth enabled on the zuul proxy:   
   `oauth2:
     resource:
         userInfoUri: https:/...../userinfo`       This works in that it requires a valid oauth token for any downstream services proxied through Zuul. However, the /health endpoint of zuul server itself is secured so I think my Eureka is having trouble pinging it to register.  The client will be calling Zuul with the token. So, how do I allow Zuul to be registered with Eureka when the proxy requires a token for a call?

Comment: Would you consider not to register Zuul with Eureka and expose it as the entry point / load balancer / proxy to the services?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to use Zuul as the proxy, and an Oauth check is enabled there (and it's working). However, what I want is for Zuul to dynamically locate all the services registered with Eureka (i.e. without specifying each 'route' in the Zuul app's application.yml). To do that, as I understand, I need to register Zuul as a DiscoveryClient, also, with Eureka. When I do that, the /health check fails when hitting Zuul, as it requires a token. Probably easiest solution would be for Zuul app to allow /health, /info endpoints to be hit without a token - if there's a way to configure that. Thanks.

Comment: Aah, interesting, I guess you would Zuul to discover every service and setup a route following tle's say convention over configuration.